# Azure git deployment - Empty dll copied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-git-deployment

I have 2 web app (1 WebApi, 1 MVC) in the same solution both referencing another project in the solution (data layer). Both web projects are set up with continuous deployment from bitbucket and everything works fine.
Since a hour or so (without doing any changes to the data layer project) the MVC project fails the git deployment (the WebApi one is fine) with the following error:

```
CSC : error CS0009: Metadata file 'D:\home\site\repository\MyProj.Data\bin\Test\MyProj.Data.dll' could not be opened -- Image is too small. [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj.Web\MyProj.Web.csproj]
```

I then logged in into the azure FTP for the MVC project and I can see that D:\home\site\repository\MyProj.Data\bin\Test\MyProj.Data.dll size is 0 bytes.

Had a look at the FTP for the WebApi project and that same dll is copied fine.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what caused that, but I would suggest the following to get to a clean state:

- Go to [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)
- Go into `D:\home\site\repository`
- Run `git clean -dxf`
- Click Redeploy in the Azure Portal

Comment: that worked great! thanks a lot. I thought the repo got a weird state but got stuck there. thanks again !

Comment: Glad to hear! If if you didn't already know about Kudu Console, hopefully it's something you'll find helpful in the future :)

Comment: Indeed, didn't know about it. Will definitely be helpful in the future. thanks again